Question about the Possibility of Measuring the Position of Particles in a Double-Slit Experiment Without Disturbing the Interference Pattern
In the double-slit experiment of particles, the reason we cannot know which slit the particle passes through while maintaining its wave-like nature is because, during the observation process, physical interactions (such as photon scattering or electromagnetic interactions) with the particle cause its state to collapse.
If it were possible to obtain information about the particle's position while maintaining the interference pattern created by the particle, I believe that, like in the Copenhagen interpretation, we could determine whether the particle passed through as a wave or as a particle, and thus narrow down the hypothesis of the current double-slit experiment.
If we could measure the spacetime distortion caused by the particle, wouldn't it be possible to know the position of the particle without affecting the interference pattern it creates?
All particles with mass and energy cause spacetime distortions. Just as we can infer the location of a black hole by measuring the distortion of spacetime, I think we could measure the spacetime distortion occurring inside a double-slit experiment setup to track the position of the particle inside the setup. Moreover, I believe that measuring this spacetime distortion would not involve the kind of physical interaction that would collapse the particle's wave function. Since the spacetime distortion itself would have been present while the interference pattern was being formed, its formation would not affect the wave-like nature.  Additionally, I think the effect of measuring this spacetime distortion on the particle would be indistinguishable from the effect that the atoms within the setup have on the particle.
I came across news about the development of ultra-precise clocks, and I saw the potential to apply such clocks to measure the curvature of spacetime. [https://www.science.org/content/article/breakthrough-promises-new-era-ultraprecise-nuclear-clocks] If we were to install these ultra-precise clocks inside the double-slit apparatus and measure the changes in the flow of time, could such measurements allow us to track the position of the particles inside the setup without destroying the interference pattern?
Of course, I think that the spacetime distortion caused by a small-mass object would be too minimal to measure with an ultra-precise clock. However, I also understand that such double-slit experiments could apply to larger polymer substances. Recently, I saw a case where a quantum double-slit experiment was successfully conducted with a protein, gramicidin.
Given this, if we were to perform the double-slit experiment with larger polymer materials and develop more precise clocks to measure the spacetime distortions caused by these larger materials, wouldn't it be possible to determine which slit the polymer passed through while maintaining its wave-like nature?
I would appreciate your opinion on whether this idea is feasible, and if not, the reasons why. Also, if in the future the molecular weight of substances in double-slit experiments increases and the clocks become more precise, would it be possible to do this?

The rule is straightforward. If it is possible, even in principle, to learn information about which slit was traversed: interference will disappear accordingly. It has nothing directly to do with “disturbing” anything.
You can place polarizers over each of the 2 slits. If aligned parallel, an interference pattern will appear. If aligned perpendicular (orthogonal), there will be no interference pattern. Either way, a polarizer is encountered. So it is not the interaction that changes things, it is the possibility of gaining which path information. Note that you don’t need to actually extract that information.
https://sciencedemonstrations.fas.harvard.edu/files/science-demonstrations/files/single_photon_paper.pdf


If it were possible to obtain information about the particle's position while maintaining the interference pattern created by the particle, I believe that, like in the Copenhagen interpretation, we could determine whether the particle passed through as a wave or as a particle, and thus narrow down the hypothesis of the current double-slit experiment.

So thought Einstein in the famous Bohr-Einstein debate. In the beginning, some of the founding fathers of Quantum Theory thought that what was behind Heisenberg uncertainty principle was our incapability to realize precise measurements of position, without disturbing the particle's momentum. Heisenberg himself reinforced this idea in his thought experiment of the Heisenberg microscope and Feynman chose this thought experiment to explain Heisenberg uncertainty relation.
But they was wrong. Precision is not the thing behind Heisenberg uncertainty relation. In the Bohr-Einstein debate, Einstein tried to figure out thought experiments to achieve high precision in position measurements, without disturbing the interference pattern. He also attempted to show how to violate the time-energy uncertainty relation. The Einstein's light box was his best attempt, and if you read it without reading the Bohr's answer, it is impossible to not get stunned by it, imagining the Quantum Theory collapsing as a wrong or inconsistent theory. But Bohr managed to recover the Heisenberg uncertainty in this experiment, and his triumph was so surprising that Einstein give up this approach, and went to his ideas about hidden variables, culminating in the EPR paper years later.
Bohr managed to recover the complementarity in the Einstein's thought experiments applying the Heisenberg uncertainty relation to the measurement apparatuses instead of the particle alone. He showed that the hypothesis of precision not only brings consequences to the particle, but also for the apparatus, thought as a quantum device. All of that culminated after in Bohr formulating his Complementary principle.

At the time of Einstein-Bohr debate, there was no way to test other mechanisms behind complementarity than measurement precision, despite thought experiments. But with the evolution of the Quantum Optics, it became possible. (Check this article, or maybe this one). What we learned is that the mechanism behind the loss of interference fringes is correlation, and the mere possibility to have access to information of the particle' path is enough to destroy the interference pattern.
Experiments using quantum entanglement made this observation even more evident. It is possible to realize the which-way measurement of one particle in another entangled particle, spatially separated of the first. In this way, the arguments about precision versus disturbance does not apply, since we don't even interact with the particle being probed (check, for example, this experimental realization of the dual slit quantum eraser).

I don't know about current measurement precision in space-time distortions, so I can't say about the feasibility of your proposal. But I can guarantee that we already achieved mechanisms allowing us to measure which-way information with precision without disturbing particle's position and we discovered that this is not the mechanics (at least, not the only one) behind complementarity.

One should note that Bohr's reply to Einsteins box argument is rather confusing and does not really yield an answer. It suggests that Quantum theory somehow needs general relativity to be consistent, which is not the case. For a good discussion of the Einstein box argument see
https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/0143-0807/33/5/1089

A point about your Zeilinger reference: entangled photons do NOT produce interference patterns, as he points out. See figure 2 of his paper. http://courses.washington.edu/ega/more_papers/zeilinger.pdf

A measurement is an interaction that produces a record of some property of a system.
In classical physics the evolution of a system is described by variables like $x(t)$ for a system's $x$ position and if you measure $x$ you get the value $x(t)$.
In quantum physics the evolution of a quantity is described by an operator called an observable. The possible outcomes of measurements on an observable are its eigenvalues and quantum physics predicts the probability of each of the possible outcomes. In general during a quantum experiment what happens to each of the possible values during the experiment: this is called interference. For an example see Section 2 of
https://arxiv.org/abs/math/9911150
When information is copied out of a quantum system, in a measurement or otherwise, interference is suppressed: this is called decoherence
https://arxiv.org/abs/1911.06282
The amount of information copied out and the time taken to copy it depends on the strength of the interaction. For objects you see in everyday life the interactions are sufficiently strong take place on scales of space and time small enough that interference is negligible. As a result quantum equations of motion without collapse predict lack of interference for objects we see in everyday life.
Variants of quantum theory that include collapse don't currently reproduce predictions of relativistic variants of quantum theory that are used to make most of the experimentally tested predictions of quantum theory
https://arxiv.org/abs/2205.00568
Gravity is a much weaker interaction than the others that objects undergo and so it is relatively bad at both measuring objects and causing them to decohere. But if gravity measures an objects position then it will also cause decoherence. There are papers about decoherence caused by gravity such as
https://arxiv.org/abs/2012.06230
